# Alter Ansible registered variable in place

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible role which will update the settings of an existing application configuration.  The role must get the settings from the application's API.  Alter a portion of the settings. Then `POST` the complete set back to the application.

```
 - name: Get Current Settings
  shell: curl -L -H "Accept: application/json" -u "{{auth}}" https://{{ server }}/api/settings
  register: settings

 - name: update settings
   <Do something to modify settings.stdout as JSON>
   register: newSettings  # Save
   when: settings.Changed = True

 - name: Post Settings
   shell: curl -L -u "{{auth}}" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {{newSettings}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the [URI module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/uri_module.html) of Ansible.

> Interacts with HTTP and HTTPS web services and supports Digest, Basic and WSSE HTTP authentication mechanisms.

You can do the first part with a `GET`:

```
- uri:
    url: http://www.example.com
    return_content: yes
  register: webpage
```

Do your data massaging and then do a `POST`:

```
- name: Example POST
  uri:
    url: https://your.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/
    method: POST
    user: your_username
    password: your_pass
    body: "{{ lookup('file','issue.json') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
```

**Edit:**

As was pointed out in the comments you can use [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/set_fact_module.html) to set the value you change from the information you receive from the `GET` call.

```
- set_fact: one_fact="something" other_fact="{{ local_var }}"
```

Inside your put you would access the new fact like you would any other variable in Ansible

Comment: I will look at the URI module.  However, it's the massaging I'm looking for help with.

Comment: Use `set_fact` to set a new variable with the result of your data massaging from the result of the `uri`

Comment: I ended up using this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025695/best-way-to-modify-json-in-ansible