# What is the best way of modifying and replacing list elements?

Tags: ansible

The original list has the following structure:

```
endpoints:
-   address: 10.10.10.1
    name: hostname1:867
    write: yes
-   address: 10.10.10.2
    name: hostname2:867
    write: yes
-   address: 10.10.10.3
    name: hostname3:867
    write: yes
```

I'm trying to create a new list by splitting the "name" field, resulting in something like this:

```
endpoints:
-   address: 10.10.10.1
    name: hostname1
    port: 867
    write: yes
-   address: 10.10.10.2
    name: hostname2
    port: 867
    write: yes
-   address: 10.10.10.3
    name: hostname3
    port: 867
    write: yes
```

I've tried a combination of json_query and map('regex_replace') and then setting a new fact but wasn't successful.

Comment: "I've tried a combination of json_query and map('regex_replace') and then setting a new fact but wasn't successful." - Showing us the code rather than the description of the code would be much more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    ep2: "{{ ep2|
             default([]) + [
             {'write': item.write,
             'address': item.address,
             'port': item.name.split(':').1,
             'name': item.name.split(':').0} ]
             }}"
  loop: "{{ endpoints }}"
- debug:
    var: ep2
```

give

```
  ep2:
  - address: 10.10.10.1
    name: hostname1
    port: '867'
    write: true
  - address: 10.10.10.2
    name: hostname2
    port: '867'
    write: true
  - address: 10.10.10.3
    name: hostname3
    port: '867'
    write: true
```

Task below is more flexible and adds items *write* and *address* only if defined

```
- set_fact:
    ep: "{{ ep|
            default([]) + [ {}|
            combine((item.write is defined)|
                     ternary({'write': item.write}, {}))|
            combine((item.address is defined)|
                     ternary({'address': item.address}, {}))|
            combine({'port': item.name.split(':').1})|
            combine({'name': item.name.split(':').0}) ]
            }}"
  loop: "{{ endpoints }}"
```

If the complete *item* can be used then the task can be simplified

```
- set_fact:
    ep: "{{ ep|
            default([]) + [
            item|
            combine({'port': item.name.split(':').1})|
            combine({'name': item.name.split(':').0}) ]
            }}"
  loop: "{{ endpoints }}"
```

If you want to try *filter_plugins* use [dict_utils](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/dict_utils/dict_utils.py). Below is the simplified *dict_add_hash* filter.

```
$ cat filter_plugins/dict_utils.py
def dict_add_hash(d, h):
    for k, v in h.iteritems():
        d[k] = v
    return d

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters. Interface to Python dictionary methods.'''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict_add_hash' : dict_add_hash
        }
```

the tasks

```
- set_fact:
    ep2: "{{ ep2|
             default([]) + [
             item|
             dict_add_hash({'port': item.name.split(':').1})|
             dict_add_hash({'name': item.name.split(':').0}) ]
             }}"
  loop: "{{ endpoints }}"
- debug:
    var: ep2
```

give the same result

```
  ep2:
  - address: 10.10.10.1
    name: hostname1
    port: '867'
    write: true
  - address: 10.10.10.2
    name: hostname2
    port: '867'
    write: true
  - address: 10.10.10.3
    name: hostname3
    port: '867'
    write: true
```

See all available [plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins).

Comment: The first method is what I was looking for! But I can see the dict_utils being handy in cases with larger data sets. Thanks!

Comment: Using the first method, is there a way to apply filters to omit a field in the newly defined dict? Example, something like `'write': item.write, | default(omit)`

Comment: Sure. Use filters *combine* and *ternary*. I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems like the logical choice to use `json_query`, I'm not sure how it would work since JMESPath (the project json_query is built on) lacks a `split` function.

You could consider writing your own filter plugin. It adds complexity for future playbook maintenance, but data manipulation in this way is so much easier in python.

In your playbook directory, create a folder called `filter_plugins` and a file `split_hostname.py` with contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {'split_hostname': split_hostname}

def split_hostname(endpoints):
    new_endpoints = []
    for endpoint in endpoints:
        hostname, port = endpoint["name"].split(":")
        endpoint["name"] = hostname
        endpoint["port"] = port
        new_endpoints.append(endpoint)
    return new_endpoints
```

Then use the filter in your playbook:

```
    - set_fact:
        new_endpoints: "{{ endpoints | split_hostname }}"
```

This is a very basic example. If you choose to go down this path, you may want to add some error handling.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to write my own if I could use what was already available. Thanks for your suggestion I will definitely keep this in mind for the future. It is similar to this idea - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025695/best-way-to-modify-json-in-ansible